# i386 exe file that refuses dosbox, on x64 windows

Tags: compilation, windows-7-x64, fortran90, i386, dosbox

I am trying to make a code run on my machine (windows 7 x64), it is a fortran 90 code that needs a third-party provided i386-based dll to work.

When I tried compiling it (with latest gfortran and mingw) to a x64 target, it refused, because of the i386 dll file. Then, I tried to compile it to a i686 target, and the compilation worked without errors.

However, the output a.exe file won't run on my x64 windows (as one could expect), and when trying to run it from Dosbox (just typing "a" or "a.exe" when I reached the correct directory), I just got "this program cannot be run in DOS mode".

So my question is: is it a fail in the compiling process, or does Dosbox reject the program for some reason (the reason being possibly that the "a.exe" program needs to write to a file when executed: it is its purpose, actually!), and if it is so, what is the reason, and is there a way to ultimately see my exe file run? on my machine?

EDIT: Dosbox indeed can run a 32 bit exe file I have from another project, so it is not Dosbox being completely non-functional. However, when trying to open that exe file directly with windows 7, it says it is incompatible with x64, while for the other file (a.exe) it just says it "fails to initialize" with code "0xC000007b"...unfortunately my compiler debugging knowledge is close to zero...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: 64-bit Windows 7 will run 32-bit programs just fine. There should be no need to use Dosbox.

Comment: Actually I installed another version of gfortran (without MinGW), and everything worked. I think my MinGW installation had something faulty...and you are right, the output file is built for 32 bit and it runs. I think the file from the other project (that does not run on windows 7) has something more: either it is 16-bit, or something else, because the error message is different!